# update method ran without errors but results are not updated

Tags: mongodb

So I need to remove the lowest hw score from collection. I ran it in mongoShell without errors. But writeresults are only matched but not modified. Can someone please tell me why?

Here is the database:

```
db.students.find( { _id : 137 } ).pretty( )
{
    "_id" : 137,
    "name" : "Tamika Schildgen",
    "scores" : [
        {
            "type" : "exam",
            "score" : 4.433956226109692
        },
        {
            "type" : "quiz",
            "score" : 65.50313785402548
        },
        {
            "type" : "homework",
            "score" : 89.5950384993947
        }
    ]
}
```

Below is my solution:

```
// sort by lowest score; writeresults are modified.
db.students.update(
    {"scores.type":"homework"},
    {$push: {"scores": { $each: [], $sort: { score: 1} }}},
    {multi: true}
)    

// should remove last element of homework; writeresults are not modified, not sure why
db.students.update(
    {"scores.type":"homework"},
    {$pop: { score: -1 }},
    {multi: true}
)
// Alternatively, below query also generated same writeresults
db.students.update(
    {},
    {$pull: { "scores": {$elemMatch: {"type": "homework"} }}},
    {multi: true}
)
```

Comment: You want `scores` in the `$pop`, not `score`.

Comment: @wdberkeley Thanks! That makes sense, removing an element in the array not the doc. How about the `$pull`, why doesn't it work?

Answer (score 0):

According to mongodb Documents, this is how you should update embedded document.

**Update Embedded Documents Using Multiple Field Matches**

The `$` operator can update the first array element that matches multiple query criteria specified with the `$elemMatch()` operator.

Consider the following document in the `students` collection whose `grades` field value is an array of embedded documents:

```
{
  _id: 4,
  grades: [
     { grade: 80, mean: 75, std: 8 },
     { grade: 85, mean: 90, std: 5 },
     { grade: 90, mean: 85, std: 3 }
  ]
}
```

In the example below, the `$` operator updates the value of the `std` field in the first embedded document that has `grade` field with a value `less than or equal to 90 and a mean field with a value greater than 80`:

```
db.students.update(
   {
     _id: 4,
     grades: { $elemMatch: { grade: { $lte: 90 }, mean: { $gt: 80 } } }
   },
   { $set: { "grades.$.std" : 6 } }
)
```

This operation updates the first embedded document that matches the criteria, namely the second embedded document in the array:

```
{
  _id: 4,
  grades: [
    { grade: 80, mean: 75, std: 8 },
    { grade: 85, mean: 90, std: 6 },
    { grade: 90, mean: 85, std: 3 }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But this query also doesn't work. Please see my edits above.